# WordPress Post ID overwritten when I create a new post?

Tags: custom-post-types

OK, this is very odd and I am totally unsure how to problem-solve this.

I am using WordPress Pods Custom Post Types.

For the last two years it has been working great.

This is the error:

1 > I "Add New" post, and WP as you'd expect, gives it an ID of let's say 1234.

2 > I then "Add New" for another post and save it as draft, and it OVERWRITES the last ID of 1234 rather than create a new ID.

It feels like there's strict caching? I've deleted cookies, etc etc but still this happens.

I also often get this error:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post.

In addition, here's an interesting discovery: nothing is sequential anymore. What I mean by that is when you click on something there is often an automatic AJAX or JavaScript action. For example, if you click "deactivate" plugin then it automatically notifies the user by saying that the plugin is deactivated.

If I refresh the page then it sometimes changes.

I suspect it must be some caching thing??

It's very odd.

Also - I live in Hong Kong and the site was unaccessible for a few hours from a bunch of different devices in different networks.

Could there be some regional caching from CloudFlare which we are using ??

Would appreciate any help in solving this riddle

ny idea what else I can do here?

Comment: What php version are you on?

Comment: Very latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was because we had (oddly) two certificates. One was loaded on the server whilst the other was with CloudFlare.

When one cert expired it caused mayhem

So. Now you know.